# MySQL duplicate key error causes a shared lock set on the duplicate index record?

Tags: mysql, database

I've read the document of MySQL 14.2.7.6. Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

My questions:

1. I don't understand why documentation states:

   > If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index
   >   record is set. This use of a shared lock can result in deadlock should
   >   there be multiple sessions trying to insert the same row if another
   >   session already has an exclusive lock. This can occur if another
   >   session deletes the row.

   Why does it set a lock on the row since the INSERT operation has
   failed. It acquires the lock for what?
2. Is an Intention shared (IS) lock set when "SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE" is executing? Is an Intention exclusive (IX) Lock set
   when "UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE" or "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" are
   executing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.1. It requires a lock on the existing entry so that subsequent attempts to insert a duplicate record fail consistently:

```sql
-- Transaction A
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO mytable VALUE(1); -- fails as "duplicate"

-- Transaction B
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE field = 1; -- must be put on hold, see below

-- Transaction A
-- transaction is still in progress
INSERT INTO mytable VALUE(1); -- must fail to stay consistent with the previous attempt
```

.2. [Yes, and yes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-lock-modes.html):

> The intention locking protocol is as follows:
>
> - Before a transaction can acquire an **S** lock on a row in table **t**, it must first acquire an **IS** or stronger lock on **t**.
> - Before a transaction can acquire an **X** lock on a row, it must first acquire an **IX** lock on **t**.

Comment: Hi. The first question. What you mean is that it acquired the lock to keep its operation in the same transaction won't be blocked ?

Comment: No, I mean the two transactions would be inconsistent if a concurrent deletion was allowed. Imagine "Transaction B" succeeds (i.e. if no lock was set by "Transaction A"). What result would you expect from the second `INSERT` attempt? Option 1: success. But this would be inconsistent with the first attempt, which failed. Option 2: it fails. But the concurrent transaction has deleted the row, so there shouldn't be a conflict.

Comment: Thanks. RS. Understand now